# JDBC executeUpdate() inserts only 1 row

Tags: java, database, jdbc

My code reads data from a text file to populate a database. The text file contains 5 lines, including a blank line (line 4). The code reads the text file but only insert the last line in the database. I also need the code to skip reading the first line in the text file.

Any help where I have gone wrong? I am new to Java Programming.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Example {
   public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Orders";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";

        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conn;
   } 
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

       String id ="";
       String firstName ="";
       String lastName ="";
       String street="";
       String city ="";
       String fileName = "src/Person.data"; 
       String line = null;


       PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
       Connection conn = null;

       try {
           FileReader fileReader = 
           new FileReader(fileName);
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
           new BufferedReader(fileReader);  


           while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

               if ( line.trim().length() == 0 ) {
                   continue;  // Skip blank lines
               } 
               String[] splited = line.split(",");
               //System.out.println(line);
               id=splited[0];
               firstName=splited[1];
               lastName=splited[2];
               street=splited[3];
               city=splited[4];
               System.out.println(line);
               System.out.println(splited[4]);

               conn = getConnection();
               conn.setAutoCommit(false);

               pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into APP.Person(PERSON_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME,STREET,CITY)values (?,?,?,?,?)");     
               pstmt.setString(1, id);
               pstmt.setString(2, firstName);
               pstmt.setString(3, lastName);
               pstmt.setString(4, street);
               pstmt.setString(5, city);
               pstmt.executeUpdate();
               conn.commit();
           }   
           bufferedReader.close();     
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
           System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");  
        ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
       }

   }   
}
```

Comment: Format your code. You have lines starting from random positions and confusing braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to insertion only gets executed for the last record. The better option is to use executebatch. first add all those insert scripts in batch and after completion of loop just execute that batch.

`Prepared statement is created inside the loop which is wrong. You need to create a Prepared statement out of the loop.`

Use try catch block as follow:

```
    try {
        FileReader fileReader =
                new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        conn = getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into APP.Person(PERSON_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME,STREET,CITY)values (?,?,?,?,?)");

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            if ( line.trim().length() == 0 ) {
                continue;  // Skip blank lines
            }
            String[] splited = line.split(",");
            //System.out.println(line);
            id=splited[0];
            firstName=splited[1];
            lastName=splited[2];
            street=splited[3];
            city=splited[4];
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println(splited[4]);


            pstmt.setString(1, id);
            pstmt.setString(2, firstName);
            pstmt.setString(3, lastName);
            pstmt.setString(4, street);
            pstmt.setString(5, city);
            pstmt.addBatch();

        }
        pstmt.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" +
                        fileName + "'");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '"
                        + fileName + "'");
    }
```

Comment: If you want to use batch execution, then you need to replace `executeUpdate` with `executeBatch`, and you should move the creation of the prepared statement out of the loop.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel true, I was just showing him the way. Updated the code. Thanks for suggetion

Comment: @Hemant thanks; I have moved the creation of the prepared statement outside the loop and used executeBatch, I am still getting the last record inserted in the database

Comment: My bad. After a clean and build, it worked. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Gokuh if my answer helped you please mark answer as accepted. please click on the yes mark near my answer.